Ubuntu 20.04 is telling me I have no space whilst I do have space
My laptop (Ubuntu 20.04) is giving me this popup telling me that I have no space left. I have looked everywhere and nothing seems to work. The only temporary fix i have is that if I reboot it works but it slowly takes more and more memory up.
This is my df -h output (it's in Swedish).

Before reboot:
folke@Nya-Laptop:~$ df -h
Filsystem   Storlek Använt Ledigt Anv% Monterat på
udev            7,8G    0   7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G   2,5M   1,6G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       234G   234G     0 100% /
tmpfs           7,8G   192M   7,6G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M   4,0K   5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7,8G    0   7,8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop4      19M 19M     0 100% /snap/freac/2981
/dev/loop3      64M 64M     0 100% /snap/core20/2182
/dev/loop5      516M   516M     0 100% /snap/gimp/418
/dev/loop6      350M   350M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143
/dev/loop1      64M 64M     0 100% /snap/core20/2105
/dev/loop2      56M 56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2796
/dev/loop7      19M 19M     0 100% /snap/freac/2996
/dev/loop0      128K   128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop8      253M   253M     0 100% /snap/dotnet-sdk/237
/dev/loop11     1,7M   1,7M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/186
/dev/loop12     497M   497M     0 100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/132
/dev/loop9      165M   165M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/194
/dev/loop13     7,3M   7,3M     0 100% /snap/notepad-plus-plus/397
/dev/loop14     30M 30M     0 100% /snap/ruby/317
/dev/loop10     253M   253M     0 100% /snap/dotnet-sdk/234
/dev/loop15     6,9M   6,9M     0 100% /snap/ngrok/118
/dev/loop17     176M   176M     0 100% /snap/spotify/74
/dev/loop16     13M 13M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/959
/dev/loop19     1,5G   1,5G     0 100% /snap/root-framework/931
/dev/loop18     219M   219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/93
/dev/loop20     178M   178M     0 100% /snap/spotify/75
/dev/loop22     454M   454M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-7-devel-core20/24
/dev/loop21     82M 82M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
/dev/loop24     348M   348M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-runtime/365
/dev/loop25     92M 92M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop23     75M 75M     0 100% /snap/core22/1033
/dev/loop26     75M 75M     0 100% /snap/core22/1122
/dev/loop27     452M   452M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-7-devel-core20/23
/dev/loop28     32M 32M     0 100% /snap/ruby/323
/dev/loop29     12M 12M     0 100% /snap/ngrok/50
/dev/loop30     13M 13M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/1113
/dev/loop31     348M   348M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-runtime/364
/dev/loop32     1,5M   1,5M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/184
/dev/loop33     1,4G   1,4G     0 100% /snap/root-framework/928
/dev/loop35     516M   516M     0 100% /snap/gimp/428
/dev/loop34     219M   219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/90
/dev/loop37     56M 56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2812
/dev/loop36     497M   497M     0 100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/141
/dev/loop38     6,8M   6,8M     0 100% /snap/notepad-plus-plus/399
/dev/loop39     497M   497M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-runtime-core20/108
/dev/loop40     106M   106M     0 100% /snap/core/16574
/dev/loop41     256K   256K     0 100% /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13
/dev/loop42     350M   350M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/140
/dev/loop43     104M   104M     0 100% /snap/core/16928
/dev/loop44     45M 45M     0 100% /snap/filezilla/17
/dev/loop45     269M   269M     0 100% /snap/firefox/4033
/dev/loop46     269M   269M     0 100% /snap/firefox/4090
/dev/loop47     494M   494M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-runtime-core20/107
/dev/loop48     165M   165M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198
/dev/loop49     323M   323M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-6-stable/19
tmpfs           1,6G    20K   1,6G   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           1,6G    36K   1,6G   1% /run/user/1002

Directly after reboot:
folke@Nya-Laptop:~$ df -h
Filsystem      Storlek Använt Ledigt Anv% Monterat på
udev              7,8G      0   7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs             1,6G   2,4M   1,6G   1% /run
/dev/sda1         234G    98G   137G  42% /
tmpfs             7,8G    12M   7,8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs             5,0M   4,0K   5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs             7,8G      0   7,8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop3         64M    64M      0 100% /snap/core20/2182
/dev/loop2        104M   104M      0 100% /snap/core/16928
/dev/loop5         64M    64M      0 100% /snap/core20/2105
/dev/loop4         75M    75M      0 100% /snap/core22/1033
/dev/loop6        253M   253M      0 100% /snap/dotnet-sdk/234
/dev/loop7        253M   253M      0 100% /snap/dotnet-sdk/237
/dev/loop0        128K   128K      0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop8         75M    75M      0 100% /snap/core22/1122
/dev/loop9        269M   269M      0 100% /snap/firefox/4033
/dev/loop10        19M    19M      0 100% /snap/freac/2981
/dev/loop11       219M   219M      0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/90
/dev/loop12       516M   516M      0 100% /snap/gimp/418
/dev/loop1        106M   106M      0 100% /snap/core/16574
/dev/loop14        56M    56M      0 100% /snap/core18/2812
/dev/loop13       165M   165M      0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198
/dev/loop15       516M   516M      0 100% /snap/gimp/428
/dev/loop17       497M   497M      0 100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/141
/dev/loop16       219M   219M      0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/93
/dev/loop19        45M    45M      0 100% /snap/filezilla/17
/dev/loop18       269M   269M      0 100% /snap/firefox/4090
/dev/loop20       350M   350M      0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/140
/dev/loop21       256K   256K      0 100% /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13
/dev/loop22       350M   350M      0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143
/dev/loop23       1,7M   1,7M      0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/186
/dev/loop24       1,4G   1,4G      0 100% /snap/root-framework/928
/dev/loop25       6,8M   6,8M      0 100% /snap/notepad-plus-plus/399
/dev/loop26        82M    82M      0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
/dev/loop27       176M   176M      0 100% /snap/spotify/74
/dev/loop28       348M   348M      0 100% /snap/wine-platform-runtime/364
/dev/loop29       1,5M   1,5M      0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/184
/dev/loop30        13M    13M      0 100% /snap/snap-store/1113
/dev/loop31       497M   497M      0 100% /snap/wine-platform-runtime-core20/108
/dev/loop32       6,9M   6,9M      0 100% /snap/ngrok/118
/dev/loop33       1,5G   1,5G      0 100% /snap/root-framework/931
/dev/loop34        13M    13M      0 100% /snap/snap-store/959
/dev/loop35       454M   454M      0 100% /snap/wine-platform-7-devel-core20/24
/dev/loop36       323M   323M      0 100% /snap/wine-platform-6-stable/19
/dev/loop37        56M    56M      0 100% /snap/core18/2796
/dev/loop38        92M    92M      0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop39       7,3M   7,3M      0 100% /snap/notepad-plus-plus/397
/dev/loop40       178M   178M      0 100% /snap/spotify/75
/dev/loop41       165M   165M      0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/194
/dev/loop42       497M   497M      0 100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/132
/dev/loop43        12M    12M      0 100% /snap/ngrok/50
/dev/loop44       348M   348M      0 100% /snap/wine-platform-runtime/365
/dev/loop45       452M   452M      0 100% /snap/wine-platform-7-devel-core20/23
/dev/loop46        32M    32M      0 100% /snap/ruby/323
/dev/loop47        19M    19M      0 100% /snap/freac/2996
/dev/loop48       494M   494M      0 100% /snap/wine-platform-runtime-core20/107
/dev/loop49        30M    30M      0 100% /snap/ruby/317
tmpfs             1,6G    16K   1,6G   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs             1,6G    28K   1,6G   1% /run/user/1002

I let it rise to 84% ant this is the output:
folke@Nya-Laptop:~$ ls -a /tmp
.
..
config-err-obI1jL
dumps
.font-unix
gameoverlayui.log
hsperfdata_unifi
.ICE-unix
MinecraftLauncher.1002
ollama1001963217
ollama1002449459
ollama100359361
ollama1009593539
ollama1012068662
ollama104932092
ollama106631077
ollama1069426939
ollama1075979683
ollama1078366468
ollama1087544160
ollama110197263
ollama1105943707
ollama1113945459
ollama1142716574
ollama1159786534
ollama1175063929
ollama121722266
ollama1225526021
ollama1228698609
ollama1234359162
ollama1261686341
ollama1288710296
ollama1306951405
ollama133308977
ollama1353071800
ollama1366243956
ollama1374327327
ollama1376393954
ollama1417705061
ollama1459225979
ollama1459919260
ollama1492419348
ollama1511114395
ollama1527990001
ollama1555918448
ollama1589100883
ollama1592001828
ollama1659825695
ollama1692387522
ollama1693664595
ollama1710473044
ollama1772207802
ollama1797164926
ollama1819603020
ollama1826734309
ollama1857229590
ollama1940636504
ollama1967984839
ollama198299138
ollama1993960883
ollama2005647413
ollama2008292668
ollama2041168227
ollama2042804763
ollama206408107
ollama2081416928
ollama209491851
ollama2111909535
ollama2112218423
ollama2132713283
ollama2142614991
ollama2157496665
ollama2173261540
ollama2201456430
ollama2201655057
ollama2203889391
ollama2210380216
ollama225504176
ollama2272500672
ollama2279092179
ollama2310586349
ollama2333191625
ollama2360111044
ollama2364207423
ollama2366120507
ollama2379808693
ollama2383780274
ollama2385638859
ollama2428766405
ollama2432594692
ollama2448718721
ollama2470750818
ollama2476738943
ollama2497734586
ollama253279352
ollama2534586687
ollama2537376317
ollama2547740269
ollama2553758033
ollama2564506667
ollama261861259
ollama2675869292
ollama2700288844
ollama2719389761
ollama2778356871
ollama281516148
ollama2838984012
ollama2846533206
ollama2860034215
ollama2863099864
ollama2878738629
ollama2913455918
ollama2990227528
ollama3005839604
ollama302604458
ollama3032303645
ollama3035256870
ollama3050556370
ollama3059590820
ollama3070300918
ollama3078197506
ollama3088092002
ollama3102855469
ollama3121640754
ollama31267931
ollama3160871421
ollama3200010951
ollama3200220999
ollama3200846063
ollama3209917065
ollama321394959
ollama3228339306
ollama324744153
ollama3256449133
ollama3271163346
ollama3283142490
ollama3289644745
ollama330204010
ollama3304402746
ollama331210225
ollama3348374229
ollama3361678237
ollama3388076876
ollama3395497432
ollama3396618447
ollama3403938379
ollama3432724067
ollama3448049219
ollama3454182899
ollama3465078273
ollama3499202924
ollama3504718132
ollama3507306007
ollama3507869838
ollama3512408714
ollama3531239816
ollama3542988988
ollama3544073904
ollama3563730584
ollama3576289114
ollama3581738109
ollama358301622
ollama3608114613
ollama3619606694
ollama3625476109
ollama363779184
ollama3641453736
ollama3649851940
ollama3668590515
ollama36854853
ollama3685701956
ollama3696561111
ollama3700855330
ollama3705584618
ollama3745950593
ollama3755918380
ollama3757442880
ollama3765001569
ollama3784272732
ollama382972485
ollama3841482715
ollama3843259758
ollama3869868686
ollama3880618199
ollama3882851846
ollama3924993310
ollama3942796655
ollama3944142899
ollama3984302837
ollama3985087269
ollama4020422033
ollama4054855846
ollama4065879845
ollama4076638783
ollama4076684727
ollama4116581390
ollama4145189079
ollama419389468
ollama4206218202
ollama4207653291
ollama4208217356
ollama4222440205
ollama4244760871
ollama4246265324
ollama4264147735
ollama435040396
ollama449754725
ollama472198794
ollama509586312
ollama516252197
ollama554925284
ollama55931083
ollama56465376
ollama565008054
ollama570864685
ollama581267448
ollama588660078
ollama596496
ollama600587617
ollama604520820
ollama646728916
ollama66144850
ollama706566305
ollama716200976
ollama731150119
ollama745381897
ollama746555448
ollama748342521
ollama754387230
ollama770624924
ollama828593765
ollama848904457
ollama849999579
ollama871668962
ollama874639690
ollama888019207
ollama891658468
ollama903565660
ollama913273938
ollama92899190
ollama932861512
ollama94177302
ollama980682688
ollama988913568
ollama993125638
ollama993513194
pressure-vessel-libs-6SEIL2
scoped_dirAFo7dU
snap-private-tmp
ssh-fftDOrv7i3jY
steam_chrome_overlay_uid1002_spid15316
steam_chrome_shmem_uid1002_spid13836
steamDdaeni
steamlPaLBH
systemd-private-a61b3c989d314968a1df223ade1aea53-apache2.service-pIDV8h
systemd-private-a61b3c989d314968a1df223ade1aea53-colord.service-uDMzjj
systemd-private-a61b3c989d314968a1df223ade1aea53-fwupd.service-YKV3tg
systemd-private-a61b3c989d314968a1df223ade1aea53-ModemManager.service-uRajph
systemd-private-a61b3c989d314968a1df223ade1aea53-switcheroo-control.service-orjHbh
systemd-private-a61b3c989d314968a1df223ade1aea53-systemd-logind.service-2qSaLh
systemd-private-a61b3c989d314968a1df223ade1aea53-systemd-resolved.service-pZHE3g
systemd-private-a61b3c989d314968a1df223ade1aea53-systemd-timesyncd.service-dukY1e
systemd-private-a61b3c989d314968a1df223ade1aea53-upower.service-0Gc5wh
.Test-unix
tracker-extract-files.1002
tracker-extract-files.121
.unifi-11849511684496055616
unifi-network-status-response
vmware-root
.X11-unix
.XIM-unix


What makes you state that you do in fact have space left? What did you check exactly? Also please post the output of df -h, IIRC that message may popup even if the you're running out of space on partitions other than / (I may be wrong, but the output will also serve as a double-check on /'s status)

The reason I say I have space left is because my father had around 170 GB worth of photos on my computer. He recently moved all of these files to a hard drive and because I was running out of space. and since then I have had these problems.
I have posted a image of the df -h output

Thanks, next time please post the output as text using copy-paste though, it's usually better that way. From what I can see, nothing explains that popup at this stage. Have you rebooted the machine since removing those files? Have you got that popup again since?

I just got that popup telling me I only have 600 MB left. I ran the the same command and I tried to screenshot it but I ran out of space so I copied it to a document (I have posted a screenshot).
Also I don't know how to post the text without it being a big blob of disgusting text.

Please remove the screenshot and paste it as a "big blob of disgusting text", select it and click on the "{}" symbol in the editor (it will add four spaces to the start of each line, making it a less disgusting blob). Also now df is showing 100% usage on /. The plot thickens. I think something may be filling up tmp if this isn't the case when, say, the pc has just been booted up. Can you reboot the machine and run df -h again to see if the usage % drops?

And next step if the usage % drops after a reboot: wait a bit until it's risen again, then run ls -a /tmp and post the output so that maybe we can understand from where whatever is filling it up comes from.

Greetings, this doesn't usually apply after a reboot, as that frees the files. But still usful to check:
Check for files deleted but still owned by a (currently) running process.
OS cannot free the disk space, unless the file owner is restarted.
Check for such files:
lsof -s | egrep "deleted|COMMAND" | less
Total number of blocks currently inaccessible as a result of this:
lsof -Fn -Fs |grep -B1 -i deleted | grep ^s  | cut -c 2- | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'

Ah, and there's your issue: large language models (like LLAMA) eat resources... you have to configure them very carefully. Good luck!

Now how do I configure them?

Jolk, if you verified that it's in fact the LLAMA files as @sarlacii suggests in your /tmp that are eating disk space fine, otherwise I should rather have said: run sudo du -h /tmp, which will also list file / folder usage and give a better hint.

I ran that command and I can see clearly that its my /tmp that's the problem and especially LLAMA, but the big question is how do I fix the problem?  Would you like me to post the output?

Not really at this point, well the thing is, we now know the problem, so this question has an answer... Which is "a process is taking up a lot of disk space",so technically this is a duplicate of the many "low disk space" / "tmp getting full" questions, and should be closed as such. You should post a different question about the usage of LLAMA, but be warned, it may get too broad / out scope for this site quickly, I suggest you just ask for basic guidance on how to set it up for low disk space consumption and that's it

I really don't need LLAMA and I wonder how I would be able to delete it safely.
Thank you for being so helpful!

I looked at the installation script (did you get it from here? https://ollama.com/download/linux), all you need to disable it should be sudo systemctl disable ollama, let me know if that works ok. Glad we helped :)

Yes, I installed it from that site but I ran that command and here's the output: Failed to disable unit: Unit file ollama.service does not exist.
I can't remember uninstalling it.

Never mind, I just ran this like before ls -a /tmp but the difference was that there wasn't a bunch of "ollama" things. So something definitely worked. I'm forever thankful for the help!!

Sorry did the command go through or not? Anyways I'll post an answer to this so that people stumbling upon this won't have to through this long chain of comments!

I looked through my terminal log with the up keys and seems that I ran it before, and it certainly works now. Thanks!

Turns out OP had installed Ollama prior to this problem showing up, and turns out that was filling /tmp pretty quickly after reboot.
While I'm sure there's a proper way to tune the daemon to work properly, since OP didn't need it anymore I suggested to run sudo systemctl disable oolama to disable the service.
That didn't go through for some reason, hopefullly we'll be able to clarify that with OP in the comments but the general answer still stands: either set up the daemon to work correctly or disable it altoghether, and that should prevent / from filling up again.
